# get minutes of float

Tags: php, time, formula

i have this code in php

```
    $minutes = date("i", $time);
    $seconds = date("s", $time);
    $hours = date("H", $time);

    $toMinutes = ($hours*60) +  $minutes +  ($seconds/60);

    $KmPerHour = $distance / ($toMinutes/60); 

    $MperMin = ($distance*1000) / $toMinutes; 

    $KmPerMin = 1/($distance/$toMinutes); 

    $MperSec =  100/(($distance*1000)/($toMinutes*60));
```

all works except this line

```
    $KmPerMin = 1/($distance/$toMinutes);
```

basicly calcule the time in minutes in running 1 kilometer (the distance is in kilometers)
but for example

10km in 00:39:00 > 39 mins results 3.9 
but it should be 3:54 mins

how i can transform 3.9 to mins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$min = 3.9;

$min = floor($min) . ':' . ($min - floor($min)) * 60; //3:54
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/CqXj3ZrB)

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you doing `min%60` rather than `floor(min)`? For values 60 or more, that really screws things up. Try 60.5 as an example, which should give you `60:30` but instead gives `0:3630` ??

Comment: That's a great point @paxdiablo, thanks. Not sure what I was thinking, or why I forgot about floor. Brain fart. I've updated my answer to reflect your advice.

Answer (score 3):

3.9 minutes *is* 3m54s, because nine tenths of a minute is fifty-four seconds.

Use the whole part `3` for minutes.

Multiply the fractional part `0.9` by `60` to get seconds.

The following PHP code:

```
$min = 3.9;

$intmin = floor($min);
$sec = ($min - $intmin) * 60;

if ($sec < 10) {
    echo $intmin.':0'.$sec;
} else {
    echo $intmin.':'.$sec;
}
```

will output:

```
3:54
```

You can even use fractional seconds, such as with `3.14159` minutes giving `3:08.4954`.

I'd provide the code for handling hours as well but, if it's taking you that long to run a kilometre, you may want to find another exercise regime :-)

---

As an aside, `KmPerMin` is the wrong sense for what you're calculating, it should more rightly be called `MinPerKm`.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
<?php
    $KmPerMin = 3.9;
    $KmPerMin = intval($KmPerMin) + (intval(( ($KmPerMin - intval($KmPerMin))*100 * 60)/100)+1)/100;
    echo $KmPerMin; // shows 3.54
?>
```

to show the $KmPerMin in 3:54 format

```
echo explode(".",$KmPerMin)[0] . ":" . explode(".",$KmPerMin)[1]; // shows 3:54
```